# Calculating $ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\delta(0)}{x} $

Tags: limits, dirac-delta

Does this limit go to $1$? I am not sure how to calculate it, because it contains the Dirac-delta generalized function on $ 0 $.
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\delta(0)}{x} $$

I came across this limit by trying to "evaluate" the following expression:
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\int_{-x/2}^{x/2} \delta(t)^2 dt}{x} $$

Comment: The Dirac-delta function is not a function to begin with. What is $\frac{\delta(0)}{1000}$, for example?

Comment: The Dirac delta is not a function. What do you mean by the expression $\delta(0)$?

Comment: I added the initial limit to my question, if this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by $\int_a^b\delta(t)^2\,\mathrm dt$, when $\delta$ is not a function and only $\int_a^bf(t)\delta(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is defined?

Comment: This question is meaningless? (since $\delta$ is not a function)

Comment: Dirac delta is an archetypal example of distributions (a.k.a. generalized functions). And although many classical operations (such as addition, differentiation, restriction to an open subset, multiplication by smooth function, composition by a smooth function from the right, convolution) are often well-defined, even the multiplication of two distributions are usually not defined. $\delta(x)^2$ is one such example. (One might possibly give it a meaning when restricted to certain subfamily of test functions, but I doubt its usefulness.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first step to solve a problem is to understand it. The Dirac delta is defined as a linear functional over continuous functions by
$$
\langle \delta_0, \varphi\rangle = ∫\varphi(y)\,\delta_0(\mathrm{d}y) = \varphi(0)
$$
In particular, one can multiply $\delta_0$ by a continuous function $f$ by the formula
$$
\langle f\,\delta_0, \varphi\rangle = \langle \delta_0, f\,\varphi\rangle = f(0)\,\varphi(0)
$$

- **First interpretation of your problem.** If $x$ is a constant (i.e. $f$ is the constant function $f(y) = \frac{1}{x}$) then for any continuous function $\varphi$
  $$
  \langle \tfrac{1}{x}\,\delta_0, \varphi\rangle = \tfrac{1}{x}\langle \delta_0, \varphi\rangle = \frac{\varphi(0)}{x}
  $$
  which converges to $0$ when $x\to \infty$, so $\tfrac{1}{x}\,\delta_0(y)\underset{x\to\infty}\to 0$ in the sense of weak convergence for measures (but this is quite a stupid problem, any distribution multiplied by $0$ gives $0$).
- **Second interpretation of your problem.** You are looking at the distribution $\frac{\delta_0(x)}{x}$. *This is **not** a well defined distribution or measure, there is no meaning to this object, I would say it is $\pm\infty$ or undefined.*
- **Third interpretation of your problem.** You actually do not care about what is happening when $x$ is close to $0$, so we can look at $\frac{\delta_0(x)}{1+x}$. This is a well defined distribution (since $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is continuous at $0$) and if one takes a test function $\varphi_x$ compactly supported in the ball of center $x$ and radius $1$ then
  $$
  \langle\tfrac{\delta_0(y)}{1+y},\varphi_x(y)\rangle_y = \varphi_x(0)
  $$
  which is $0$ as soon as $x>1$, and so,
  $$
  \langle\tfrac{\delta_0(y)}{1+y},\varphi_x(y)\rangle_y \underset{x\to\infty}\to 0.
  $$
  Remark however that $\tfrac{\delta_0(y)}{1+y} = \delta_0$ so it was not very useful to multiply by this function here. The above result just tells us that $\langle\delta_0,\varphi_x\rangle \underset{x\to\infty}\to 0$ but this is trivial since $\delta_0$ is supported in $0$ (i.e. $\delta_0$ "is $0$ in all points except $0$") ...

---

EDIT (since you edited your post):

- $\delta^2$ has no meaning (or $+\infty$)!
- If you remove the square: $∫_{-x/2}^{x/2} \delta(\mathrm{d}t) = 1$, so
  $$
  \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{∫_{-x/2}^{x/2} \delta(\mathrm{d}t)}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0
  $$